# Can I get more aliens?

Tags: ben-10-protector-of-earth

I just bought Ben 10 for PS2 last Saturday and I just finished it. The problem is that there are only 5 aliens. Heatblast, FourArms, XLR8, WildVine, and CannonBolt. I was wondering if you can more aliens. Like Diamond Head, WildMutt, GrayMatter, Upgrade, Ripjaws, Stink Fly or GhostFreak with the Halloween trio.

Comment: I don't think that tag is relevant, and there are multiple ben10 games for PS2, please clarify.

Comment: Ben 10 protector of earth ps2